# How can you replace all occurrences of this token in a String?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a String that looks like this:

```
"My favorite color is {color:tan}."
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a javascript function that replaces all occurrences of the token with whatever color I pass in, but defaults to "tan" if the String is too long.

E.g.

```
var string = "My favorite color is {color:tan}.";
var favoriteColor = "red"; 
var maxLength = 25;
var tokenPrefix = "color"
var result = replaceToken(string, favoriteColor, maxLength, tokenPrefix);
```

Now "result" should equal `"My favorite color is red."`, because the string is 25 characters long.

But if I set `favoriteColor = "purple"`, then result should equal `"My favorite color is tan."`, because the word "purple" would cause the string to be longer than 25 characters.

I'm not familiar with regex, so I'm not sure if this is possible in regex, but I've tried to do this using an indexOf() to find the token, but there may be multiple instances.  I also tried a replaceAll(), but because it's not a simple string, it won't really work.

Comment: Is the "token" always `{color:XXX}` or are there spaces, can XXX include braces (i.e.`{,}`), can there be other keywords besides "color", like `{flavor:XXX}` or `{texture:XXX}`

Comment: Also, ditto for what @ColinDeClue Said.

Comment: Try replacing with `/\{color:(\w+)\}/`

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex, so I didn't know if it is possible to do this with regex. I tried using indexOf() to get the start and end position of the tokens, but it quickly became a mess once I started thinking about multiple tokens in a string.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr XXX can include spaces, but no brackets.  Yes there can be other keywords.  I will update the function to take in a keyword too.

Comment: @elclanrs Not sure what you mean.  What would I replace with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely ways to optimize this, but as a quick one off, here is an example of how to do it:

```
replaceToken(string, favoriteColor, maxLength) {
  tokens = string.match(/{(.*?)}/)
  color = tokens[1].split(':')[1]
  if (favoriteColor.length < maxLength) string = string.replace(tokens[0], favoriteColor)
  else string = string.replace(tokens[0], color)
  return string
}
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, but it doesn't look at token prefix.  Say I had one token with "color" as the prefix, and another with "song".  How could we specify only to replace the one with "color"?

Comment: @Brian perhaps you use this to write your own code, work until you get stuck and try with a different question?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm sorry, I was thinking I had to change the regex, which I had no idea where to even begin.  I now see that I can get it from the tokens array.